# Convertendo Bases em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

O código abaixo, recebe um número decimal e converte para bases de 2 a 9

```
def converte(numDecimal, base):
    if numDecimal != 0:
        numConvertido = ""
        while numDecimal > 0:
            resto = numDecimal % base
            numConvertido = str(resto) + numConvertido
            numDecimal = numDecimal // base
    else:
        numConvertido = "0"
    return numConvertido


n = int(input())
while n != -1:
    for b in range(2, 9 + 1):
        r = converte(n, b)
        print(r, end=" ")
    print()
n = int(input())
```

Caso agora eu queira fazer ao contrário, e receber um número binário e converter para bases de 3 a 10, por exemplo, como eu faria?

Comment: O mais simples é interpretar o binario como decimal e de seguida usar a função que já tem de convesão para outras bases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa, saudações! Cara existe um jeito mais fácil de converter números em bases diferentes para inteiros na base decimal, vou dar um exemplo abaixo:
Abaixo é um conversão de um número(String) binário para a base decimal:

```
b = '0111'
print(int(b, 2))
>> 7
```

O int() nesse caso recebe dois parâmetros, o primeiro sendo o número a ser convertido que deve ser passado como string, e o segundo a base em que ele se encontra, então podemos fazer outro exemplo em que um número está na base 5 e queremos convertê-lo para decimal:

```
b = '0410'
print(int(b, 5))
>> 105
```

Sabendo disso, acho que facilita bastante a construção do seu código!
Agora sendo direto a sua pergunta, ao receber um número binário e querer passá-lo para outras bases, o melhor seria convertê-lo para decimal e então para a base em questão utilizando a função que já tens.